# How to Merge Data based on the Key within the Dictionary while retaining the Keys in the output in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

There is a dictionary of the following format: **[List Containing Dictionaries]**

```
[{'ID': '743987', 'Information': 'Anime is the Best'},
 {'ID': '743987','Information': 'Python is the Best'}]
```

**Required Output:**

```
[
{'ID': '743987','Information': ['Anime is the Best','Python is the Best']}
]
```

I've seen the other solutions, but none seem to produce the following output:

> [
> {'ID': '743987','Information': ['Anime is the Best','Python is the Best']}
> ]

It is necessary for '**ID**' and '**Information**' to be a part of the output.

How to proceed with this?

Comment: [{'ID': '743987', 'Information': 'Anime is the Best'},
 {'ID': '743987','Information': 'Python is the Best'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
a = [{'ID': '743987', 'Information': 'Anime is the Best'},
 {'ID': '743987','Information': 'Python is the Best'}]
for i in a:
    for key in i.keys():
        if key == 'ID':
            res[key] = i[key]
        else:
            res[key].append(i[key])
print(dict(res))
```

Output

```
{'ID': '743987', 'Information': ['Anime is the Best', 'Python is the Best']}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the output in the following format: {'ID': '743987','Information': ['Anime is the Best','Python is the Best']}?

Comment: The updated code will do that.

Comment: It is only working for that string unlike the last version of the code. For example: a = [{'ID': '743987', 'Information': 'Anime is the Best'},
 {'ID': '743987','Information': 'Python is the Best'},
    {'ID': '743S87','Information': 'OOOOOOO'}] then the generated output is: {'ID': '743S87', 'Information': ['Anime is the Best', 'Python is the Best', 'OOOOOOO']}, completely skips the first ID and combines all the Information Values even though the keys are different.